# Error loading rsa private key - MUP to Deploy Meteor App at Digital Ocean w/SSL

Tags: ssl, meteor, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean, pem

I have a Meteor app I am deploying to a Digital Ocean Ubuntu server via [MUP](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up). It works great without SSL, but I can't figure out the SSL part.

I Purchased a Comodo SSL Cert. They sent me 4 .crt files. I can the following command:

```
cat cert1.crt cert2.crt cert3.crt mydomain.crt > ssl.pem
```

I then put that `ssl.pem` file in the root directory locally. Added `"ssl": {"pem":"./ssl.pem"}` to my `mup.json` file and ran `mup setup` -- everything is succesful until:

```
[45.55.225.190] x Verifying SSL Configurations (ssl.pem): FAILED
    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    Trying to initialize SSL contexts with your certificatesError loading rsa private key
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot this. I ran a quick `find` on the server and the `ssl.pem` is there, so mup successfully sent the file over, but it seems `stud` is not verifying the file or not finding it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I was running into two different problems. First, you have the put the certificate files in a very specific order. Second, I was not including my key file. The command to create the .pem file needed was:

```
cat mydomain.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt mydomain.nopass.key > ssl.pem
```

[This blog](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/installing-comodo-positivessl-certificate-bundled-with-root-and-intermediate-ca-certificates-on-apache) post at DeveloperSide.NET helped me tremendously.

Comment: Thanks this just saved me